# Can't access correct cell when pulling value from Excel to Word Text Form Field

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pull data from Excel and place it into a word Text Form Field. The code below works except that it will not pull data from the cell I specify -- it pulls the text from a different cell. I can see that the correct cell is being selected in Excel because it is outline, but it simply does not pull the data from it. I have messed around trying different cells and with some it pulls the data I want and with others it pulls data from a different cell.

Anyone know reaons why this might be happening and how I can resolve it? Thanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wrdApp
Dim wrdDoc
Dim Data

ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 1).Activate
Data = Selection.Cells(8, 1).Value

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True

Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("H:\jpmDesk\Desktop\VBA tester.docx")

With wrdDoc

wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Text1").Select
wrdApp.Selection.Range.Text = Data

End With

Set wrdDoc = Nothing
Set wrdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the top left cell 0,0 or 1,1?? You have to know this so you can calculate the x and y offset of each cell.

Comment: Top left is 1, 1. And unfortunately I have to access this specific info or what I've done is useless.

Could it have to do with there being merged cells in my spreadsheet? I imagine it has to be something with how my cells are formatted in Excel...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Data = Selection.Cells(8, 1).Value
```

to

```
Data = Selection.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace existing code:

```
    ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 1).Activate
    Data = Selection.Cells(8, 1).Value
```

With this:

```
    Data = Range("A1").Offset(7, 0).Value
```

`Cells(8,1).Value` is not the same as `Range("A1").Offset(7,0).Value`

By using the offset method of the Range object, you can now retrieve values without actually selecting the cell.

Step through your code in VBE by using F8 to see how this works.